# Why is ul aligned to the bottom

Tags: css, html-lists, vertical-alignment, html

I have been seriously messing with this one thing for over an hour now. Basically I have a navigation bar, there is an icon on the far left, and the links are aligning to the bottom of the image.

I have tried messing with padding, margins, line height, vertical-align and everything else I could think of. I also tried having the image inside and before the ul. I need the ul items (will be links) to be vertically aligned to the center of the icon.

I have put all the code into one file that I will copy here. Also, when you post please explain why a solution will work, not just post code. The other posts I searched for about this before I posted here didn't explain anything, just included code that didn't help when I tried it. Unfortunately, because I have no idea what the solution is or what it relates to I am including all of the code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*background-color: #10f009;*/
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
img {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.smallSection {
  margin: 100px;
}
.paragraph {
  font-size: 2em;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 2.4em;
}
.list {
  list-style: solid inside url("");
  font-size: 2em;
}
.nav-link {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.nav-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.largeSection {} #section1 {
  background-image: url("../img/placeholder.jpg")
}
#nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align: top;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 1;
}
/*temporary*/

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Dawn Little -->
<div id="section1" class="largeSection">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <div style="width:70px;height:70px;border: 1px solid red;display: inline-block;">
        <!-- The img link is obviously broken so this is here instead. -->
      </div>
      <!-- <img src="img/herbfalife-icon.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="nav-icon"> -->
      <li class="nav-link">Who am I</li>
      <li class="nav-link">What I do</li>
      <li class="nav-link">3-Day Trial</li>
      <li class="nav-link">Challenges</li>
      <li class="nav-link">Become a Coach</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="smallSection">
    <p class="paragraph">
      <span class="title">Client Name<br /></span> Hi, I'm a wife, mother, and Personal Wellness Coach with Herbalife Nutrition. My super power - I change lives.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- What I do -->
<div id="section2" class="largeSection">
  <div class="smallSection">
    <p class="paragraph">
      <span class="title">What I do</span>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Wellness Evaluations</li>
        <li>Nutrition Coaching</li>
        <li>Impact Lifestyle</li>
        <li>Get Results</li>
        <li>Coach Coaches</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 3-day trial -->
<div id="section3" class="largeSection">
  <div class="smallSection">
    <p class="title">
      Try Our 3-Day Trial
    </p>
    <p class="title">
      What you get:
    </p>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Personal Wellness Coach</li>
      <li>Wellness Evaluation</li>
      <li>Meal Plan</li>
      <li>Daily Support</li>
      <li>Plan of Action</li>
      <li>6 Meals</li>
      <li>Metabolism Booster</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Challenges -->
<div id="section4" class="largeSection">
  <div class="smallSection">
    <p class="title">
      Join a Weight Loss Challenge
    </p>
    <p class="title">What you get:</p>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Personal Wellness Evaluation</li>
      <li>Personalized Program</li>
      <li>Nutrition Classes</li>
      <li>ommunity of Support</li>
      <li>Accountability</li>
      <li>Opportunity to Win Cash &amp Prizes</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Become a coach -->
<div id="section5" class="largeSection">
  <div class="smallSection">
    <p class="title">
      Become a Coach
    </p>
    <p class="title">
      What you get:
    </p>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Opportunity to Change Lives</li>
      <li>Opportunity for Personal &amp Financial Growth</li>
      <li>Training</li>
      <li>Potential to Change Lives in Over 90 Countries</li>
      <li>Be Part of a Team</li>
      <li>Get in the Best Shape You've Ever Been</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found a solution that technically works but it's a little hacky. I had to make the #nav height and line-height both 70px. The image was still about 26px too high (or the links were 26px too low) so I relative aligned the image down by that much. If somebody has a better solution I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This way that you are coding is a bit tricky to align.I will rewrite your code.  However, I recommend you to use a CSS framework like bootstrap or zurb.

Firstly, you need to rewrite HTML part like

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="header clearfix">
     <div class="logo">
          <!-- The img link is obviously broken so this is here instead. -->
     </div>
     <div class="nagivation">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li class="nav-link">Who am I</li>
        <li class="nav-link">What I do </li>
        <li class="nav-link">3-Day Trial</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Challenges</li>
        <li class="nav-link">Become a Coach</li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have added `header` and `nagivation` 
then add these lines to your css to

```
  .clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */

.header{
  min-height:70px;
  clear:both
}
.logo{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}
.nagivation{
  width:80%;
  float:right;
}
```

you need to remove `#nav` also in your CSS code.

based on your needs, you can change this class

```
.nagivation #nav{

// add needed adjustment  
}
```

you can have an access to all codes here https://jsfiddle.net/mhadaily/7f152z3r/

Comment: Out of the responses this one seems to have worked the best. It is too late for my brain to work through what you did, but I will look at it in the morning and if it is still the best answer I will mark it as such. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the only elements that should be inside a `<ul>` are `<li>`. That `<div>` (or link or whatever it is in reality) may cause you grief.

The real problem, however, is that you're using the wrong CSS property on the wrong element. You want `vertical-align` (not "align"), and it should be applied to the list-items (not the container).

Try this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-link"><!-- img here --></li>
  <li class="nav-link">Who am I</li>
  <li class="nav-link">What I do</li>
  <li class="nav-link">3-Day Trial</li>
  <li class="nav-link">Challenges</li>
  <li class="nav-link">Become a Coach</li>
</ul>
```

with

```
.nav-link { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: the align thing was a test (one of many). Aso to the vertical align, I tried that in every way it is possible to try it. In all of the relevant sections without any solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I tried my solution with your given code, and it works just fine... Is there more context and/or other requirements that you haven't told us?

Comment: No, I think I copied all the relevant code in, I'm using chrome, are you using another? I doubt that is it but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to simply float the icon as seen in the css below and in [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOgaQX).

```
    #nav {
      border: 1px solid red;
      height:100px;
      line-height:1;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .nav-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float:left;
     }
```

Floats force other elements to flow around the floated element. You just want to be wary of floats because they wreak havoc on your layout if you're not vigilant (they collapse their parent containers). You can read all about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Comment: Hey thanks, this looks promising. However when I looked at your pen link it shows the text as aligned to the top of the image. It needs to be aligned to the middle.

Comment: Hey, I looked at the pen again, and all I had to do was relative align it so it would be in the middle of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a UI expert. But By looking at the following tag I can asked you few question to understand? Because You are writing non-li tags within ul. Try ti wrap your code with li tag.
Just go to w3cshool link.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <div style="width:70px;height:70px;border: 1px solid red;display: inline-block;">
      <!-- The img link is obviously broken so this is here instead. -->
    </div>
    <!-- <img src="img/herbfalife-icon.png" width="70px" height="70px" class="nav-icon"> -->
    <li class="nav-link">Who am I</li>
    <li class="nav-link">What I do </li>
```

Comment: Oh, that is probably because I was frustrated and impatient by the time I had copied the code into SO so it wasn't completely in a way that made sense. I did try it with the image inside an li tag, as well as outside the ul altogether, and obviously without an li tag inside the ul. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply moving the `li` elements up a little bit?

```
.nav-link { 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, I can't remember the result right now, and it's late so I'm not going to try it right now, but it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I used it with the exact code you provided, and it worked for me. Please give it another try when you are able.

Comment: Ah I see what I did. I had tried to relative align top, instead of bottom. Your solution did work, however I decided to actually just relative align the image, so there is a little space between the image and the top of the page. I must have been really tired last night to not see that possibility.